# Define a variable as range

Tags: r, variables, range

This might be a stupid question but can I define a variable as a range so that the following would result in TRUE?

```
range1 <- range(0.001-0.002)
0.0015 %in% range1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `findInterval`:

```
range1 <- c(0.001,0.002)
findInterval(0.0015,range1)==1
[1] TRUE
```

The interval is open on the upper limit by default though (ie 0.002 is not included).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you write your own operator:

```
'%bw%'<-function(x,rng){
  (x >= rng[1]) & (x <= rng[2]) 
}

rng<-range(c(2,5))

3 %bw% rng

TRUE
```